# Firebase - One to Many relationship & Queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It's been a while since heard about Firebase and I decided to start a small project of mine last week.

I've read many articles about database structure and I came up with two solutions for my database:

**Case 1**

Table **B** has the references, via the *ownerId*, to the records in table **A**

```
{
    "A" : {
        "user-id-1" : {
            "name": "James",
            "number": "11111"
        },
        "user-id-2" : {
            "name": "Rob",
            "number": "11111"
        },
        ...
    },

    "B" : {
        "id-b-1" : {
            "something": "value1",
            "ownerId" : {
                "user-id-1": true 
            }
        },
        "id-b-2" : {
            "something": "value2",
            "ownerId" : {
                "user-id-2": true 
            }
        },
        "id-b-3" : {
            "something": "value3",
            "ownerId" : {
                "user-id-2": true 
            }
        },
        "id-b-4" : {
            "something": "value4",
            "ownerId" : {
                "user-id-1": true 
            }
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

**Case 2**

Table **A** has the references, via the **Bs** array, to the records in table **B**

```
{
    "A" : {
        "user-id-1" : {
            "name": "James",
            "number": "11111"
            "Bs": {
                "id-b-1": true,
                "id-b-4": true,
                "id-b-7": true,
            }
        },
        "user-id-2" : {
            "name": "Rob",
            "number": "11111"
            "Bs": {
                "id-b-2": true,
                "id-b-3": true,
                "id-b-6": true,
            }
        },
        ...
    },

    "B" : {
        "id-b-1" : {
            "something": "value1",
        },
        "id-b-2" : {
            "something": "value2",
        },
        "id-b-3" : {
            "something": "value3",
        },
        "id-b-4" : {
            "something": "value4",
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

In table **A** the IDs of the records are the same as the IDs assinged to the logged-in user, *user-id-1*, since I can not add more properties to the user object provided by firebase.

I'd like to say that the records related between A and B can grow to thousands of records.

So there is a one-to-many relationship between **A** and **B**.

Let's say I want to retrieve all the **Bs** related to the **user-id-1**:

1. Which database structure is better in this situatio, according to your experience?
2. How can I retrieve all the **Bs** objects, by running only one query on the database?
3. Can I use a sort of *where* clause which allows me to filter the **Bs** by looking at the *ownerId* value?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure seems to be describing a "Many to many" relationship but on different sides. since in "Case 1" ownerId can contain more than one id:

```
"ownerId": 
{
    "user-id-1": true, 
    "user-id-1": true 
}
```

and in "Case 2" two of the "Bs" can contain the same Id:

```
"user-id-1" : {
       "name": "James",
       "Bs": {
           "id-b-1": true
       }
   },
   "user-id-2" : {
       "name": "Rob",
       "Bs": {
           "id-b-1": true
       }
   }
```

In both cases you have one "A" owning multiple "Bs" and one "B" being owned by multiple "As".

To make this One to many I would suggest to use "Case 1" and change the object to

```
"id-b-4" : {
    "something": "value4",
    "ownerId" :  "user-id-1"
}
```

This will allow only one owner of the item. 
In "Case 2" nothing can enforce having unique "Bs" for each "A". And it will also make queries hard.

All that said, both cases are viable in my opinion, it depends on how are you using those objects, since the selling point of Firebase is the real time data you should choose the one that is more relevant for your use case. If you are observing "As" chose Case 2. If you are observing "Bs" choose "Case 1". Or you can use both, whatever makes you life easier.